# transfer back msg.value to caller on error

Tags: error, require

I have a function with modifier 'payable' in the contract. My understading is, msg.value gets added to the contract's balance and then further code is executed. 
First question, is this a correct understading ?
Second question, how do i send back msg.value to caller if there is a error, i could think of doing this,

```
if(<check for error case>){
  msg.sender.send(msg.value)
}
```

or is there a way to use 'require'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to signal an error and return a user's funcds is to use the `revert`, `assert`, or `require` operations. All of these will return any funds sent in the transaction. For example, your code may look like

```
assert(!error);
```

or

```
require(conditions, "Error message");
```

or

```
if(error)
    revert("Error message");
```

Note that `require` and `revert` return any unused gas to the sender, while `assert` consumes all unused gas. It is usually preferable to use `require`.

For more documentation see http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/control-structures.html?highlight=revert#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

> First question, is this a correct understading ?

**Yes**

> Second question, how do i send back msg.value to caller if there is a error

If you use `send`, you will need to use it inside a `require` since it doesn't throw an error if the transfer of `eth` fails. You can use `transfer` instead of `send` then, which checks for you if it successfully transfered the `eth`.

Example :

```
if (error) {
    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

> is there a way to use 'require'?

**Yes**, it depends on your code. I consider it a preferable way than your first solution.